# Form inputs don't create record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, sqlite, haml

I am using paperclip and dropbox for images.

I am not sure why I am getting this. Some of the solutions i tried for resolving the sqlite3 busy exception error didn't work.

But I also suspect my parameters somehow aren't correct...
the controller specifies i need a character object, but the parameters don't seem to have that. I know i use a file attachment called `:image`, but paperclip, imagemagick, and dropbox are supposed to handle the creation of the image attributes once the image gets uploaded and the form is submitted.

---

This is the error I get in my browser.

[image]

**Form:**
    = form_for(@character, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|

```
- if @character.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
        %h2= "#{pluralize(@character.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this character from being saved:"
        %ul
            - @character.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li= msg

#stripe_error.alert.alert-danger{ :style => "display:none" }
    %noscript JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.

.form-group
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
.form-group
    = f.label :image
    = f.file_field :image   
.action
    = f.submit
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
@character = Character.new(character_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @character.save
    format.html { redirect_to @character, notice: 'Character was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @character }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @character.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

...

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_character
  @character = Character.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def character_params
  params.require(:character).permit(:name, :image)
end
end
```

**Gemfile:** (yes, did bundle install)

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use Haml for views
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~> 3.0.3.0"
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.0"
gem 'paperclip-dropbox', ">= 1.1.7"



group :development do

    gem 'nokogiri'

    #gem 'hpricot', '0.8.6'


gem 'ruby_parser', '~> 3.1.1'

# erubis is already included in action pack
    gem 'html2haml'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: any save hooks in the model?

Comment: no. i actually found out this was simply a sqlite viewer error. I deleted some sequences in there and it was making it a busyexception.

i closed the sqlite viewer, restarted it, and the deleted sequences were back, and so was my ability to save (i.e. not get busyexception)

how do i mark this as answered or cleaered?

Comment: if you ever post to stackoverflow again, please include the error you get in plaintext. otherwise it's not searchable for google and on the stackoverflow page.